# HttpSecurity antMatchers for different port

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-boot

I have a Spring-Boot app with the actuator and security starter dependencies.
I want to secure the actuator-endpoints with HTTP-basic-auth.
The following code works as intended, IF the `mangagment.port` is the default one.
But I want to set this property to `mangagment.port=9000`.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/admin/**").fullyAuthenticated()
                .and()
                .httpBasic()
                .and()
                .csrf().disable();
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("user").password("4321").roles("USER", "ADMIN");
    }
}
```

How can I secure differnt ports?

Do I have to use a port-mapper as following and if so, does that have any security concerns?

```
.portMapper()
      .http(9090).mapsTo(9443)
      .http(80).mapsTo(443);
```